# DateTimeOffset in Log4Net

Tags: log4net, datetimeoffset

What is log4net.Layout.PatternLayout value to output DateTimeOffset data type to database?

This is what I have currently in configuration file for log4net:

```
<log4net>
....
<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
</parameter>
...
</log4net>
```

And I want to have something like:

```
<log4net>
....
<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTimeOffset" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff **OFFSET**}" />
</parameter>
...
</log4net>
```

Basically we reuse the same DB to log events from clients located in different time zones - so we want to know an exact local time of the event.

Thanks,
  Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use any valid [DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  Try this:

```
%date{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz}
```

Comment: It helped me, thanks. But there was still a missing part for me: datetimeoffset dbType was requiring its size. (Adding node `<size value="7" />` after `dbType` node.)

Answer (score 0):

Would defining your DB column as DateTime and using `%utcdate` instead of `%date` help?  That should make all of the timestamps compatible.

Comment: I do need to store DateTimeOffset in SQL database to know client's local DateTime. UTC time does not have timezone info from the client. offset is 0 for UTC.